# Java regular expression to process the string Object with nested data

Tags: java, regex, string

Below is the string data which is a string object and i should be able to filter out all the **CrMetaDataReqV1** and **CreateConReqV1** which is encapsulated inside rectangular brackets.

Also,it would be great if someone can regex expression you think is right.

Below is the the string with nested data.

```
[
 CreateDocReqV1(docMetaD=CrMetaDataReqV1(documentName=string, documentType=pdf), docContent=CreateConReqV1(data=abc)),

 CreateDocReqV1(docMetaD=CrMetaDataReqV1(documentName=string, documentType=pdf), docContent=CreateConReqV1(data=def)), 

 CreateDocReqV1(docMetaD=CrMetaDataReqV1(documentName=string, documentType=pdf), docContent=CreateConReqV1(data=ghk))

 ]
```

From the above String i should be able to split and be able to process as a separate string value's as  **CrMetaDataReqV1** and  **CreateConReqV1**

Expected o/p:

```
 CrMetaDataReqV1(documentName=string, documentType=pdf)
 CreateConReqV1(data=abc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
CrMetaDataReqV1[(][^)]*[)]
```

and

```
CreateConReqV1[(][^)]*[)]
```

You can of course use non-greedy too: `[(].*?[)]`